# Making header div to be exactly fixed into parent rounded corner div

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I created the round corner div which contains header and content div's.The code is as follows:

```
<div class="borderRadius">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="content">content goes here</div>
</div>
```

The classes are goes like this in head section

```
.borderRadius {border:1px solid #dadada; border-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius:15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; }
.header { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F7F6;height: 25px;padding: 4px 10px 0;text-align: left; }
.content{ width:auto; }
```

Now,I want the header div should exactly fit into the rounded corner parent div such that the header div corners should not cover the rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is really simple, I`m sure that you just missed it: you should put corner radius to .header class too ;-) Like this:

```
.borderRadius {border:1px solid #dadada; border-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius:15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; }
.header { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F7F6;height: 25px;padding: 4px 10px 0;text-align: left; border-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius:15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px;}
.content{ width:auto; }
```

I have tested it on Opera, FF, Chrome and IE9 (IE9+ only supports border-radius CSS3), hope that helps.